# Uploading an image to WebAPI without using forms

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm having trouble with WebAPI in getting the request content. I'm using a .NET 4 solution and want to save an image that comes up from the client.

The client code is

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
  File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\dylan_000\Pictures\image.png").CopyTo(stream);
  stream.Flush();
}
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

The WebApi method looks like this

```
public Task<bool> Image()
{
  return Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith<bool>(t =>
    {
        using (var writer = File.Create("this was uploaded.png"))
                        {
                            (t.Result as Stream).CopyTo(ms);
                            writer.Flush();
                        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

The size of the streams don't match and the image that gets saved is not valid.

The code pasted above is just enough to replicate my situation, obviously there are better ways to save the image, but in my case it goes off for further processing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to repro your issue. BTW, I however modified the following highlighted code though before trying. What is 'ms' here? sounds like memory stream?

(t.Result as Stream).CopyTo(**writer**);

Comment: whoops you're right ms is a memory stream, my copying and pasting skills at work.

Answer (score 0):

Lesson leaned here,
In order to get around authorization I was manually inserting the cookies to the request. It appears I was ham fisted in doing this and that was the reason for the problem. For anyone who wants to upload images with WebAPI the code above will work fine. (Just be sure to keep the request clean)